# SecretKeyFactory.getInstance gives me NoSuchAlgorithmException no matter what algorithm I provide

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cryptography

So I have been looking at this page: https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/SecretKeyFactory.html

They appear to claim that any of those algorithms should work with SecretKeyFactory in Android-Studio but when I put in this code:

```
SecretKeyFactory key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("Algorithm-Name");
```

No matter what algorithm name I put in that is listed on that android website, it always gives me

> Unhandled exception: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException

I tried it in eclipse with a standard Java project and it worked fine.

I tried using spongycastle too but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Well `SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("Algorithm-Name")` is *never* going to work, is it? Suppose you get specific and provide a *correct* line of code that isn't working?

Comment: You've tried every algorithm in there? Could you show us the stack trace for a specific one? Did you possibly change or remove providers from your runtime? What runtime / SDK are you using? You could try listing the algorithms by iterating over all the providers & services in your runtime...

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something wrong with your provider configuration. You could try and list which algorithms are available using the following code:

```
Provider[] providers = Security.getProviders();
for (Provider provider : providers) {
    boolean printedProvider = false;
    Set<Service> services = provider.getServices();
    for (Service service : services) {
        String algorithm = service.getAlgorithm();
        String type = service.getType();
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("SecretKeyFactory")) {
            if (!printedProvider) {
                System.out.printf("%n === %s ===%n%n", provider.getName());
                printedProvider = true;
            }
            System.out.printf("Type: %s alg: %s%n", type, algorithm);
        }
    }
}
```

If this doesn't print anything then create an *empty* project for the same runtime, and run it again. If it does show an algorithm - and it should - then you should make sure that the printed provider is available in your project configuration.

If it doesn't, you should really reinstall the SDK or runtimes, as there is something seriously wrong with the project setup.

Comment: Also make sure you're using the right `SecretKeyFactory` class; some providers mimic the class name structure used by the JCA API, making for some horrible coding mistakes.